# Laravel 5 - Updates in config files does not reflect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, config

I'm using Laravel Framework version 5.0.33 at the time of creating this question.

Changes made to any config file eg: app.php or database.php does not reflect the same while accessing them using:

```
config('app.variableName');
```

or

```
Config::get('app.variableName');
```

Here is how config variables are set (eg: in config/app.php)

```
<?php

return [
    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),
    'url' => '',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'locale' => 'en',
    'fallback_locale' => 'en',
    'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString'),
    // ...
];
```

**FYI:**
Permissions to app, config, storage are already set to 777 (read+write+execute).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you should store app variables in your `.env` file.

Comment: Thank you Raphael, but this config values will have their default values as opposed to "environment-specific" values. Much appreciated the alternative you suggest but I'm looking for answer to above question.

Comment: Post a bit more code.  How are the config variables stored?  How are they pulled?

Comment: Where and how are you setting `app.variableName`?

Comment: Environment-specific doesn't have to exclude default values. You can store a value in your `.env` file on your local machine that is the same as a value stored on your production machine. I understand what you're trying to do, but it feels like your circumventing Laravel 5's best practices, and "reinventing the wheel".

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you very much for sharing best practices, however, this didn't not solve the problem. Re-phrasing my question "Why are the changes made in config variables not reflected while accessing them?"

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately, I don't have an answer to your specific, as the last time I used `Config::get()` was a Laravel 4.2 application from a while back. Maybe I can look into this a little more later.